# Draw square in java without Java Graphics

Tags: java, draw

How would we make a square pattern on a canvas, given two of its coordinates.

The following function is supposed to draw a square with the given coordinates (x1,y1), (x3,y3) on the canvas of size 20x16 -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DrawMe(20, 16, 16, 14, 8, 14);        
}

    public static void DrawMe(int yaxis, int xaxis, int x1, int y1, int x3, int y3) { 
    int l=Math.abs(x3-x1); int l2=l/2;
    int x2=x1+l2; int y2=y1+l2;
    int x4=x1+l2; int y4=y1-l2;
    char [ ] [ ] canvas = new char [xaxis] [yaxis]; 
    for (int x = 0; x < xaxis; x++) { 
        for (int y = 0; y < yaxis; y++) { 

            if((y==x1 && x==y1) || (y==x2 && x==y2) || (y==x3 && x==y3) || (y==x4 && x==y4))
                //canvas[x][y]='#';
                System.out.print('#');

            else { 
                //canvas[x][y]='.'; 
                System.out.print('.');
            }                
        }  
        System.out.println();
    }/
}
```

But, the code gives me an output like this -

```
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
........#.......#...                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................
```

Whereas I want something like this -

```
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
....................                                                                                                                                                                                 
............#.......
..........#####.....
.........#######....
........#########...
.........#######....
```

I tried many things but it is just not happening. Could anyone please help me figuring it out? It'd be a great help!

Please excuse me if the question seems silly. Just trying to get some basics clear. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Technically, you are drawing a diamond not a square. I suggest that you start by just drawing the top # of the diamond. Can you get that at the correct location?

Comment: This is a very well worded question. You give a complete code example that I can compile and run myself, if I wish, and you give both the actual output and expected output. I wish that more new members of Stack Overflow were this thorough.

Comment: Thank you, @Code-Apprentice.
Well, technically I am trying to draw any quadrilateral with the given set of coordinates. Here, I am given two, trying to find out the other two.
Do you think that if I try to make diamond with the loop, that would accommodate general cases?

Comment: oh... that is a bit more complicated. You are basically doing a scanline algorithm. I suggest googling that word.

Comment: Note that you have plotted the two calculated corners. I suggest doing this more deliberately, though. In fact, I suggest plotting all four corners as an exercise to get headed in the approximately correct direction.

Comment: And you should edit your question to state the general problem you are solving. This should clarify the specific example you already wrote.

Comment: I just noticed you have some weirdness in the names of your variables. You should be consistent with which direction is called x and which is called y. It usually helps to use the traditional horizontal x-axis but not necessary. The important part is to avoid mismatches like `x==y1`.

Answer (score 0):

ok, my answer is unclear due to my lack of english skill.
i just put my source code below

---

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test= new Test();
    test.DrawMe(20, 16, 16, 14, 8, 14);        
}

/*
 * if you want to draw diamond from 2 points on same X-axis,
 * this is short solution that i think.
 * 
 * But you want to draw rectangle from 2 diagonal points on any location,
 * variables should be changed to float or double for calculating REAL NUMBER,
 * and then other math algorithm is needed.
 */

public void DrawMe(int xaxis, int yaxis, int x1, int y1, int x3, int y3) { 
    int length = Math.abs(x3-x1);
    int harfLength = length / 2; 

    int minX = (x1 > x3) ? x3 : x1;
    int maxX = (x1 > x3) ? x1 : x3;

    int minY = y1 - harfLength;

    for(int y = 0; y < yaxis+1; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < xaxis+1; x++) {
            if(x > minX+(Math.abs(y-minY)) && x < maxX-(Math.abs(y-minY))) {
                System.out.print('#');                  
            } else {
                System.out.print('.');
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

}
```

---

and this is a result.

```
.....................
.....................
.....................
.....................
.....................
.....................
.....................
............#........
...........###.......
..........#####......
.........#######.....
..........#####......
...........###.......
............#........
.....................
.....................
.....................
```

Comment: Since the OP is doing text graphics, int is the correct data type.

Comment: i don't think that text graphics is different from plotting graphics. is that any difference?

Comment: you are right. However, your original answer did not really address the problem. You current answer is a bit too much because you essentially did the OPs homework for them.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i think he want to scanline problem solving so that I just give to him an advice for data type error that easily occured in that cases. but my lack of language skill may be making some trouble.

Comment: yes, the OP's comment below the question sounds like this is a scanline exercise. I try very hard to be forgiving of English skills and focus on what you mean. Sometimes that is difficult. Answering questions here is a great way to practice your language skills.